# Regular Expressions in Python for match files in a folder

Tags: python, regex

I want to match all the files in a folder using regular expressions for some reason:
I used this:

```
re.compile(r'\.*$')
```

But this is also matching hidden files and temp files.
Is there a better option?

Comment: The pattern as-is makes not much sense (endswith zero or more dots, i.e. all and everything). Neither did you mention why you don't use glob, which is intended for the purpose.

Comment: I initially tried.. re.compile(r'\.[a-zA-Z]{,3}') assuming, filenames end with .txt, or .pdf or .xml i.e. three characters after the dot. didnt work either.

Comment: yes, you make sense. silly mistake.

Comment: @maddy: What do you mean by temp files?

Comment: @maddy: in your your first try, `{,3}` means "zero up to three", and it needs to be anchored at the end of the string. It is fine with a couple of changes: `r'\.[a-zA-Z]{3}$'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes the assumption that you're wanting to do something with these file names. As someone mentioned in the comments you should use `glob`. Since I'm not sure what you're going for with the 'temp' files this was the simplest thing. It will return no hidden files. Files is a list of file paths from your current working directory.

```
import os, glob
files = [f for f in glob.glob('./*') if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try re.compile(r'\w+\.*\w*') to match alphanumeric file names with a possible dot extension.

\w+ matches one or more alphanumeric file names [a-zA-Z0-9_]

\.* matches zero or more '.' characters

\w* matches zero or more file extension alphanumeric characters.

[Kodos](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/) is an excellent Python regular expression developer/debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Get all files from a directory just using this:

```
import os
files = [f for p, d, f in os.walk('/foo/bar')][0]
```